# Does Mavericks break the ability to create a wifi network that other devices can connect to?

Tags: macos, wifi, android

I'm not talking about sharing an Ethernet connection via Wifi, but about creating a separate WiFi network, not connected to the Internet.

In previous versions of OS X, I could create a wifi network by clicking the wifi network in the status bar and choosing "Create Network..."

I can still do that in Mavericks, but my Nexus 7 does not see the network I created.

My iPhone does see the network, but in a separate section called Devices, below the normal wifi networks. When I connect, it warns that the wifi network is not connected to the Internet. When I ask it to proceed, it connects, but immediately turns on 3G so that it remains connected to the Internet. It looks like in the process of adding this intelligence between their devices (Mac and iOS), Apple broke the ability of non-Apple devices, like the Nexus 7 in this example, to see and connect to the network.

Does anyone know about this, and how to create a wifi network that non-Apple devices can connect to?

The Mac is a 2012 Retina Macbook Pro, 15-inch, and the Nexus 7 is a 2012 model.

Comment: I noticed if I use no security it seems to work but if I use WEP(128bit) it doesn't. That used to work fine in the past

Comment: http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Answer (score 1):

It still works fine in Mavericks for me. All devices can connect to the networks that I create, so I don't think anything's changed in the OS with regard to this. Creating a non-Apple network should be the same process as creating any Ad-Hoc network.

Comment: I tried again, but I don't see the wifi network on my Nexus 5 or Nexus 7.

Comment: Report it here http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html